# Iterating ArrayList and adding to another arrayList with specific format

Tags: java, list, collections

Effecient way of adding to ArrayList

I have an arrayList as follows:

```
Name    id  zone    cases
Test    12  Above   20
Test1   13  In      30
Test1   13  Above   12
Test1   13  Below   10
Test1   14  Above   2
Test1   14  In      8
Test1   14  Below   6
```

I have to iterate this arrayList and create result list of this type

```
Name    id  zone    cases
Test    12  Above   20
Test    12  In      0
Test    12  Below   0
Total               20
Test1   13  Above   30
Test1   13  In      12
Test1   13  Below   10
Total               52
Test1   14  Above   2
Test1   14  In      8
Test1   14  Below   6
Total               16
```

Though Name 'Test' did not have 'In' and 'Below' I have to add these values to list with 0 cases. It should be dynamic iteration but 'Above', 'In' and 'Below' are static.
Also name will have more than one id like test1 has id 13 and 14. And each section should have a section called 'Total' added to the list. Any suggestions please?

Comment: So, for each ID, add elements to ensure that there ends up being an "Above"-"End"-"Below"-"Total"? What would have happened in the 2nd list if the 1st list had a n element of the form `Test3 15 Below 4`?

Comment: What is `dynamic iteration`? Have you tried any approach to solve this, and how far did you get?

Comment: I meant the names are dynamic and id can be any values. It is not necessary to have value Name='Test' or id = '12' or 13'...

Comment: @tucuxi I startedand I am so confused on how to proceed hence asking for suggestions.

Comment: Start with actual classes whose instances can be truly stored in an `ArrayList`, instead of those tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Classes should be like this. This is what you are looking. Just put some unique id logic if you want like that. DO some more logic process if Level are just Above/In/Below. Initilaize them on beginning and update data on those

public enum Level {

```
Above("Above"),
In("In"),
Below("Below");

private String level;

Level(String level) {
    this.level =level;
}

public String getLevel() {
    return level;
}
```

}

public class Test {

```
private String name;

private Integer id;

private Level level;

private Integer count;

public Test(String name, Integer id, Level level, Integer count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.level = level;
    this.count = count;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Level getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public void setLevel(Level level) {
    this.level = level;
}

public Integer getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(Integer count) {
    this.count = count;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Test [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + ", level=" + level
            + ", count=" + count + "]";
}
```

}

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Aggregator {

```
private Set<Test> testList;

private int totalCount;

public Aggregator() {
    if(testList==null)
        testList = new HashSet<Test>();
    totalCount=0;
}

public void addTest(Test test) {
    testList.add(test);
    totalCount = totalCount + test.getCount();
}

public Set<Test> getTestList() {
    return testList;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Aggregator [testList=" + testList + ", totalCount="
            + totalCount + "]";
}

public int getTotalCount() {
    return totalCount;
}

public void setTotalCount(int totalCount) {
    this.totalCount = totalCount;
}
```

}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Structure {

```
private List<Aggregator> data;

public Structure() {
    if(data==null) {
        data = new ArrayList<Aggregator>();
    }
}

public List<Aggregator> getData() {
    return data;
}
```

}

import java.util.List;

public class AggregatorTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Structure structure = new Structure();
    List<Aggregator> finalData = structure.getData();
    Test test = new Test("Test", 1, Level.Above, 10);
    Test test1 = new Test("Test", 1, Level.In, 10);
    Test test2 = new Test("Test1", 2, Level.Above, 10);
    Test test3 = new Test("Test1", 2, Level.In, 10);

    Aggregator aggregator = new Aggregator();
    aggregator.addTest(test);
    aggregator.addTest(test1);

    Aggregator aggregator2 = new Aggregator();
    aggregator2.addTest(test2);
    aggregator2.addTest(test3);

    finalData.add(aggregator);
    finalData.add(aggregator2);
    for (Aggregator entry : finalData) {
        System.out.println(entry);
    }

}
```

}

Output:

Aggregator [testList=[Test [name=Test, id=1, level=Above, count=10], Test [name=Test, id=1, level=In, count=10]], totalCount=20]
Aggregator [testList=[Test [name=Test1, id=2, level=Above, count=10], Test [name=Test1, id=2, level=In, count=10]], totalCount=20]